# XCode 7.1.1 TableViewCell's Content View narrower than cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ipad

Since upgrading an older Swift 1.1 (I think) project to the latest XCode and swift syntax, the Storyboard seems all messed up. The most glaring bug that I can't seem to solve is in a UITableView.

I have a UITableViewCell with a standard Content View inside, which XCode wants to be 810px wide, as opposed to the cell, which is 1024px wide.

I've tried to fix this by opening the storyboard in source code mode and changing the 810 to 1024, but the changed value reverts to 810 when reopening the storyboard back in the default "graphics" mode.

```
...
<tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="8zh-sj-0jQ" id="fLL-9o-aQq">
    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="810" height="43"/>
    ...
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you post the inspector view for the scene in the storyboard that has the  issue. I would review my constraints.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever you do to **UITableViewCell**'s content view, is not gonna matter really as it'll be set right before getting drawn on screen by the **UITableView**. My suggestion is to reset all layout settings for *contentView* and use layout constraints for the views inside the *contentView*. If it still doesn't occupy the entire space, check and see if your **UITableView** is wide enough.

Answer (score 0):

Every tableview cell has a default cell size which is set in the storyboard. 
[image]

Try changing in that place. Make sure your cell size matches here.[image]